# How to limit compiler flags only to a (my) local library?

Tags: c++, cmake, compiler-warnings, catkin

I am trying the example below :

```
add_library(
        mylib
        src/my_code.cpp)

target_include_directories(mylib
        PUBLIC include ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${thirdPartyLib_INCLUDE_DIRS})

add_dependencies(
        mylib
        ${mylib_EXPORTED_TARGETS}
        ${catkin_EXPORTED_TARGETS})


target_link_libraries(mylib
        PUBLIC
        ${thirdPartyLib_LIBRARY} ${catkin_LIBRARIES})

target_compile_options(mylib PRIVATE -Werror -Wall -Wextra)
```

The issue is that the compile options also propagate to `thirdPartyLib`, yet I need them only for `mylib`.

Comment: It is not possible that the compile options from `mylib` propagates to `thirdPartyLib` from what you have shown here. They must come from somewhere else. You don't have a `add_compile_options` with the same warning options set in a parent `CMakeLists.txt`?

Comment: If I comment `target_compile_options` then no issues

Comment: You have an extra `${ ` next to `${catkin_LIBRARIES}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the problem is compiler warnings, which are generated by included `thirdPartyLib` header files when compiling file `my_code.cpp`.

If you want your compiler not to generate warnings from included third-party header files, you can for example in gcc/clang include them as "system headers" (command line option `-isystem` instead of `-I`).

To do this in CMake use `SYSTEM` option in `target_include_directories`:

```
target_include_directories(mylib
    SYSTEM
        PUBLIC ${thirdPartyLib_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)
```

Comment: Did not for me. Note that when I use `target_compile_options mylib INTERFACE -Werror -Wall -Wextra)` then no warning is considered.

Comment: Option `INTERFACE` means that code that links to your library (target `mylib`) will be compiled with options `-Werror ...` but not the code of your library. So by changing `PRIVATE` to `INTERFACE` you are turning off these options for `mylib`source files.

Comment: If you use `make` to build your project you can run it as follows: `make VERBOSE=1` and inspect command line compiler options and see compilation of which files generates warnings.

Comment: In fact I had to what you suggest to another depending custom lib. Thanks! Works now.